# How to insert a picture in an R Markdown chunk using a relative file path

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, filepath

I have two folders (folder1, and folder2) nested inside my project_folder. Folder2 is my working directory and it is where I kept my RMarkdown files and their output. Folder1 is where I keep my picture and data files. I am trying to insert a .jpg file from folder1 while compiling and working in the folder 2 directory. I tried to do this:

````
```{r Chunk1, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, error = FALSE, comment = NA, fig.align = "center", results = 'asis'}

#Set the wd one step back

knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = setwd('..')) 

#Call the picture

knitr::include_graphics('/folder1/external/picture1.jpg')


```
````

But I keep receiving the error that the program cannot find the file:

```
Error in knitr::include_graphics("/folder1/external/picture1.jpg") : Cannot find the file(s): "/folder1/external/picture1.jpg" Calls: <Anonymous> . . . withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> <Anonymous> In addition: Warning message: package 'knitr' was built under R version 3.5.2. Execution halted.
```

Is there another way to do this?
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is you are giving it a wring path. Try addind "../" before the path and make sure that you get to the right place. (After putting "../" if you press TAB you can see in which directory you are and choose the relevant picture file name.

```
knitr::include_graphics('../folder1/external/picture1.jpg')
```

Comment: Pressing TAB is very helpful. But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: let's try another way then. try this: ![caption.](path) (notice that now you don't need quotes around the path) Not in a chunk either (not as code)

Comment: What I found to work was adding another / before the folder path starts, so:
    knitr::include_graphics('..//folder1/external/picture1.jpg', error = FALSE) 

I'm not really sure why this works, I think it has something to do with how the computer reads the file names.